# To display Gender with name instead of showing true or false.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have 2 tables candidate and job. candidate table have gender field. job table have male and female. if click the job or candidate it will go to the details page. In this page i have gender like 0 or 1. it doesn't show the name male or female. Because in table i stored values like 0 or 1 only. but i need the UI page must display the name.i need help.

my code is in details page,

```
<p>
      <strong>Gender :</strong>
      <%: Html.Encode(Model.Gender) %>
</p>
```

i have an idea. To give if condition this one how to code?

Comment: why code is not displaying? i put here itself.<p>
               <strong>Gender :</strong>
               <%: Html.Encode(Model.Gender) %></p>

Comment: You really need to go thru FAQs before posting questions. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model.Gender is integer with value 1 or 0, isn't it?

You can do the following:

```
<p>
  <strong>Gender :</strong>
  <%: Html.Encode(Model.Gender==1?"male":"female") %>
</p>
```

Of course, it is better to pass viewModel object (with string property ("male"|"female")) to your View.